# STM32F1x Exceptions, piority and NVIC

Tags: stm32

I'm a little bit confused about exceptions and NVIC.
In ARM there are two main kinds of exceptions. Those related to core and those outside of core, peripheral.
As far as i know from some book NVIC mainly control outside the core exceptions. Moreover we have two separate registers holding piority number of exceptions Interrupt priority registers (NVIC_IPRx) and System handler priority registers (SHPRx).
How these two groups of exceptions are related to each other through NVIC?

Answer (score 0):

Check [programming manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/5b/ca/8d/83/56/7f/40/08/CD00228163.pdf/files/CD00228163.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00228163.pdf), chapter 2.3, specifically chapter 2.3.5.

> All exceptions have an associated priority, with a lower priority value indicating a higher priority. Priorities are configurable for all exceptions except Reset, Hard fault, and NMI. If software does not configure any priorities, then all exceptions with a configurable priority have a priority of 0.

[...]

> Configurable priority values are in the range 0-15. This means that the Reset, Hard fault, and NMI exceptions, with fixed negative priority values, always have higher priority than any other exception.For example, assigning a higher priority value to IRQ[0] and a lower priority value to IRQ[1] means that IRQ[1] has higher priority than IRQ[0]. If both IRQ[1] and IRQ[0] are asserted, IRQ[1](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/5b/ca/8d/83/56/7f/40/08/CD00228163.pdf/files/CD00228163.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00228163.pdf) is processed before IRQ[0].If multiple pending exceptions have the same priority, the pending exception with the lowest exception number takes precedence. For example, if both IRQ[0] and IRQ[1] are pending and have the same priority, then IRQ[0] is processed before IRQ[1].

Answer (score 0):

ARM Cortex M provides several kinds of exceptions, but to summarize they are: interrupts (used mostly by peripherals), faults (for example memory violation) and exceptions dedicated to OS implementation (Supervisor Call, SysTick etc...). There is also the Reset and the NMI. Reset has the higher priority, then comes the NMI. The other exceptions priorities are configurable, through two sets of registers:

- NVIC_IPRx for interrupts
- SHPRx for System Handlers (ie. Faults + SVC, SysTick and PendSV)

Now, the lower prioriy value, the higher priority is the exception. That's why Reset and NMI have negative priorities.

Comment: Do all of these exceptions go to NVIC? Is there a simply way to calculate piority? This all groupinig seems to be a little bit complicated

Comment: No, as far as I understood, the NVIC manages the interrupts, the other exceptions are managed by System Control Block or by the core directly.I don't know what you mean by calculate priority. Do you mean deciding what interrupt must be more prioritary than others ? It is usually common sense and not too complicated. For example say you have one communicaiton protocol whose bandwith is challenging, its priority will be high. The Systick priority may be high too to keep it accurate. etc...

Comment: About the priority grouping, it is another level of control: you can set different (sub)priority levels in a set of interrupts. The difference is that among the same prioriy group, it is not preemptive. You don't have to use it if you're not sure you need it.